Clarification on Differentiating a Scalar Field Perturbed by a Small Vector
I am currently working through a proof involving the gradient of a scalar field, and I've hit a roadblock in understanding a particular step.
I only have some basic familiarity with calculus of multiple variables and of the proofs of results.
Background information:
Given a scalar function $\varphi(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$, I want to use the defintion of a gradient that involves a perturbation $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a}$, where $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ is a constant vector and $\alpha$ is a small parameter.
This leads to the perturbed function:
$$
\varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a}) = \varphi(x_1 + \alpha a_1, x_2 + \alpha a_2, x_3 + \alpha a_3).
$$
To find the gradient, I'm considering the derivative of $\varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a})$ with respect to $\alpha$. By the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a}) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial \varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a})}{\partial (x_i + \alpha a_i)} \frac{\partial (x_i + \alpha a_i)}{\partial \alpha}.
$$
Given that $\frac{d(x_i + \alpha a_i)}{d\alpha} = a_i$, this simplifies to:
$$
\frac{d}{d\alpha} \varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a}) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial \varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a})}{\partial (x_i + \alpha a_i)} a_i.
$$
I am stuck now, I do not know how to proceed. I think I should first, somehow rewrite the remaining differential on the RHS. Second, evaluate it and then set $\alpha = 0$ as per the definition.
I do not know how to evaluate the differential, can we even simplify it? Would I try and use some sort of taylor expansion (not sure even what this would be for functions of multiple variables)?
I would then obtain the result I want:
$$
\frac{d}{d\alpha} \varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a})\Big|_{\alpha = 0} = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial \varphi(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_i} \cdot a_i.
$$
I appreciate any insights or correction on where my understanding falters!

I don't understand what you mean by (1) but (2) seems alright. Notice, your final result is basically $\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{a}$

Thank you for commenting. I actually did notice this already, but to obtain this I would need to evaluate $\frac{\partial \varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{a})}{\partial (x_i + \alpha a_i)}$ and then set $\alpha$ to $0$ to obtain $\frac{\partial \varphi(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_i}$, which is not clear to me, and serves as the main purpose of the post.
